# Thread abortion not happening on File Writing

Tags: c#, multithreading, file-handling

I have file reading/writing mechanism from my WPF Application. I am reading a file(100,000) records and grouping in based on "Account Type" field in the file.
Each account type has seperate output files.

I am doing this in threaded communication for better output file writing.

Now My question is suppose if a user is cancelling the file writing from WPF Button. I am aborting the particular thread.
But Still the file writing mechanism is happenings after aborting the thread.

Is there any way to stop writing the file once it gets canceled by the user

Comment: How long does it continue? Is the file completed? How do you Abort the thread?  How do you start the thread?

Comment: the file writing is completed till the file input file is completely writing successfully

Comment: Take a look at [CancellationTokenSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtokensource.aspx) and [CancellationToken](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Code the thread that does the file writing to stop when the user hits the cancel button. Any time you find yourself trying to "reach into" a thread from the outside to "force it" to do the right thing, stop. Take a step back. And think to yourself, "Why didn't I code this thread to do what, and only what, I wanted it to do in the first place?"